# NSURL:URLByAppendingPathComponent: converts ? into %3F, but then UIWebView undoes that conversion resulting in load failures

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I'm loading a local html page and within shouldStartLoadWithRequest: with the following url:

```
... /Library/Application%20Support/CDS/%3Fpid=27ce1ef8-c75e-403b-aea1-db1ae31e05cc/...
```

within that page if a user clicks on a link to go to an external web site, then they click on the back button my code deals with it with:

```
if ([self.webView canGoBack])
    [self.webView goBack];
```

However when shouldStartLoadWithRequest: gets called again as a result of  calling [self.webView goBack] the URL that gets passed to shouldStartLoadWithRequest: has been changed to:

```
`... /Library/Application%20Support/CDS/?pid=27ce1ef8-c75e-403b-aea1-db1ae31e05cc/..`.
```

i.e. the OS has changed the "%3F" within the URL to "?".

I return YES from shouldStartLoadWithRequest: but due to "%3f" turning to "?" has the consequence that didFailLoadWithError: gets called with WebKitErrorDomain 102 and the page fails to load.

The file actually has ? in its name but it is the iOS system calls that convert that into %3F during the process of building up the NSURL object which is passed to UIWebView:loadRequest: as follows

```
NSURL *fullURL = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForDirectory:NSApplicationSupportDirectory                                                                                 inDomain:NSUserDomainMask
                                                                          appropriateForURL:nil 
                                                                                           create: YES
                                                                                               error:&err];

fullURL = [fullURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:folderLocation isDirectory:YES];
fullRUL = [fullURL URLByAppendingPathComponent: pageToLoad isDirectory:NO];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL: fullURL];      
[self.webView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

folderLocation is an NSString that contains the ?, the call to URLByAppendingPathComponent automatically converts this into %3F, without that conversion the page load fails.

Has anybody seen this before?

Comment: did you solve the problem already? I am experiencing the same issue when loading a local html file with get parameters.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not using file url's but I had the same issue.
Looks like this is the best way to deal with it.

```
NSString *newURLString = [[origurl absoluteString] stringByAppendingPathComponent:appendedString];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:newURLString];
```

Answer (score 1):

Query params must be added with relativeToURL method.
Try following code ;

```
NSURL *baseUrl = [self.baseURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/api_url"]];

NSString *urlString = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"?param1=%@&param2=%@", param1, param2] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString relativeToURL:baseUrl];
NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the same problem in this way:

`let baseRequest = "yourURLString"`

`let URLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: baseRequest)!)`

The most important thing is to pass the URLRequest as a URL created by a String.